# If $B_A\cup B_B$ is a basis for $E$, then not necessarely $E=A\oplus B$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $\mathbb R^3$ and an endomorphism $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$. Suppose we are given $A$ the matrix of $f$ relative to the canonical bases, and from which we determine that $\{v_1\}$ is a basis for $\ker f$ and $\{v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis for $ \operatorname{im}(f) $. And we want to show that $\mathbb R^3= \ker f \oplus \operatorname{im} f$.

Is it correct to say that since the determinant of the matrix $[v_1v_2v_3]$ is nonzero then we necessarely have that $ \mathbb R^3= \ker f \oplus \operatorname{im} f$.

My opinion is that it is not correct to do this. Because we only have the following implication: **If** 1) $E=A\oplus B$ and 2) $B_A$ is a basis for $A$, $B_B$ is a basis for $B$ **Then** 3) $B_A\cup B_B$ is a basis for $E$.

But we don't have that 3) implies 1) and 2). The only use of this statement is in case determinant of $[v_1v_2v_3]$ is zero and then we can say that $\mathbb R^3\not = \ker f \oplus \operatorname{im} f$.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: 3) implies 1) and 2). If $B_A \cup B_B$ is a basis of $E$, every $x \in E$ has a unique representation as a linear combination of the basis vectors. Prtition them, and you have a unique representation of $x$ as a sum of elements of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: That is true of course!!! Thank you Daniel!